# How to show this countable problem

Tags: set-theory

I am trying to prove this statement about countability:

Let $a\subset b$, if $b$ is countable then $a$ is countable.

Comment: $\Bbb N \subset \Bbb R$, and $\Bbb N$ is countable, yet $\Bbb R$ is not.

Comment: I apologies for that mistake should correct the question

Comment: Now if a is subset of b, you can always define a inclusion mapping from a to b such that f(x) = x for each x in a.

Comment: What definition of countability do you know?

Comment: See [Subset of Countable Set is Countable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subset_of_Countable_Set_is_Countable).

Comment: Basically, show that an injection from $a$ to $b$ exists (trivial to construct this map by "embedding" $a$ into $b$) which would prove the claim.